# C# SendKey loop stuck

Tags: c#, loops, infinite

So, i've been trying to use SendKey.Send method with a for loop, and for some reason it gets stuck in an infinite loop only when i use it there. I've tried the code without it, and it worked for some reason.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < trackBar2.Value; i++)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(trackBar1.Value);
        }
    }
```

What seems to be the problem?

*EDIT: It can't be the "Enter" key because it does the same thing with other keys and strings, for example:

```
SendKey.Send("a");
```

Comment: What's the value of `trackBar2.Value` when it gets stuck?

Comment: Is the Enter not sent to button1, causing you to recursively press the button?

Comment: It's between 1-150. I don't think it really matters because i've tried various values. @TimRogers

Comment: I don't think the Enter casues it, because i've tried it with different keys and strings. @MicroVirus

Comment: So the same happens if you, for instance, send 'a'?

Comment: Yes, same thing exactly. @MicroVirus

Comment: How infinite a loop? I have tried to reproduce the problem, and yes when I press the button it hangs for a time (as to be expected, because you are sleeping the thread), but after a while it responds again. Note that using Enter would cause an infinite loop, because then you keep calling button1_Click again and again.

Comment: TrackBar1 & TrackBar2. -> Debug.Log(value) => check output window. [guess: Thread.Sleep(a very long time)]

Comment: Well, when i press the button it just keeps sending the key infinitely, without ever responding again, even when not using Enter... Have you used the exact same code as mine? @MicroVirus

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted your example into a new project, and added two trackbars and a button. Observed behaviour: `{ENTER}` -> infinite loop, other key -> hangs for a bit then continues. If you go to another window, you'll find the `Enter` being sent, and if you stay away from your window it should come out of its loop.

Comment: You're right, it starts responding again after a while, but the sleep caused the loop work more than once (after it gets to the max value it starts again from 0 and so on for a couple of times). I guess it really is the sleep. Is there any replacement for the sleep method which would not cause that? @MicroVirus

Comment: I think Hans Passant said this in his answer, that was around for a couple of seconds: What are you trying to do? Most likely, SendKeys isn't the answer, and this sounds like an X-Y problem (see, for instance, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/262009 ). So explain, perhaps in a new question, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, what i've been trying to do is to create a program which will automatically type in a any textbox (like on notepad or chats), best solution i could come up with is SendKey. @MicroVirus

Comment: `SendKeys` sends keys to whatever window/control has focus. To properly test it, you could add a textbox control to the form, and then in `button1_Click` first set focus to the textbox using `Select`.

Answer (score 3):

You press button1, at which time the code shown will be executed. This then sends Enter to button1 (because this still has focus), causing that code to run again, etc.

Thus, you have created a loop.

If you try with a different key sent, for instance `a`, then the program will hang for a bit, due to the `Thread.Sleep`, but after that should become responsive again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running your `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");` in a background thread. I am not sure why it is blocking your main thread but the following approach is working.

```
  static void Main()
    {
        // setup some form state
        Form form = new Form();

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        // start the worker when the form loads
        form.Load += delegate
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        };
        worker.DoWork += delegate
        {
            // this code happens on a background thread, so doesn't
            // block the UI while running - but shouldn't talk
            // directly to any controls
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Item " + i);
                Thread.Sleep(150);
            }
        };
        worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object sender,
           ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

After five hundred iterations my application responded back.